# Remove border from win32 button

Tags: winapi, button

I have a button which is created in the WM_CREATE function of a Win32 Application with the following code:

```
hChangeWorldButton = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    "BUTTON",
    "OK",
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_FLAT | BS_BITMAP,
    2,
    2,
    25,
    25,
    hWnd,
    (HMENU)CHANGEWORLD_BUTTON,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);
SendMessage(hChangeWorldButton, BM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)worldBmp);
```

I would like the button to show only the image. Not the background and border.

How can I do this? I have tried many different button styles from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but nothing seems to fit my needs. I was thinking of using BS_OWNERDRAW but it seems a bit overkill. Or is it the only solution?

Finally, how can I change the cursor to be a hand when it's hovering over the button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No button style is available that results in the visual representation you are after. You would have to go with `BS_OWNERDRAW` here.

As an alternative you could use a [Static Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760769.aspx) with the [`SS_NOTIFY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760773.aspx) style instead. A static control allows you to get the visual representation you want, and the `SS_NOTIFY` styles allows you to respond to mouse input. However, you will not be able to implement a keyboard interface.

While I have not tried this myself, it may also be possible to get the desired effect by using a [Command Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511455.aspx) ([`BS_COMMANDLINK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775951.aspx#BS_COMMANDLINK)), and setting the caption to an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To eliminate the button's background and border simply make the button smaller than the bitmap.